# Need help on an example of a stabilizer using $S_{26}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S_{26}$ act on the alphabet in the ordinary sense e.g. a, b, c, etc, and let $X$ be the set of all finite sequences of letters, $x=x_1\cdots x_n$ where $x\in X.$ Then let $S_{26}$ act on $X$ defined by $\sigma(x)=\sigma(x_1)\cdots\sigma(x_n).$ Suppose that $\sigma=(5\:16\:20\:8)(1\:15).$ Prove that $$\{\phi\in S_{26}:\phi(TOP)=HAT\}=\{\sigma\psi:\psi\in Stab_{S_{26}}(TOP)\}.$$

I can prove one direction, by assuming the right hand set first then arriving at the left hand set but I'm having trouble proving the other way. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is $\sigma$ in the definition of $H$? Also, your $G$ and $H$ are not groups, so it is IMHO a bit questionable (but not incorrect per se) to denote them with those letters.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I forgot to include it in the first post, but now its updated.

Comment: Ok, better! So presumably we can assume that $\sigma(TOP)=HAT$? without checking :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes.

Comment: Whenever you have a group $G$ acting on some set $X$ you get that if $g_0\cdot a=b$ for some $g_0\in G$, $a,b\in X$, then 
$$\{g\in G\mid g\cdot a=b\}=g_0 \operatorname{Stab}_G(a).$$ I would think that this is explained while proving the orbit-stabilizer theorem, but I'm not 100 per cent :-)

Comment: It is more or less equivalent to the fact that in that setting
$$\operatorname{Stab}_G(b)=g_0\operatorname{Stab}_G(a)g_0^{-1}.$$ In other words, that the stabilizers of two elements in the same orbit are conjugate subgroups.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen we haven't used orbits yet. But either way, how is this related to the problem?

Comment: Ah! In that case I jumped the gun a bit, sorry about that. This is then a useful exercise! Can you show that if $\phi(TOP)=HAT$ then $(\sigma^{-1}\phi)(TOP)=TOP$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sure. Since $\sigma^{-1} (HAT)=TOP$, then we have $(\sigma^{-1}\phi)(TOP)=\sigma^{-1}(\phi(TOP))=\sigma^{-1}(HAT)=TOP.$ So does this mean $\sigma^{-1}\phi = \sigma\psi$??

Comment: Not quite. But you did show that $\sigma^{-1}\phi$ is in the stabilizer, so $\sigma^{-1}\phi=\psi$ implying that $\phi=??$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah I see. Implying that $\phi=\sigma\psi$ which is what we wanted to show. But what if $\sigma^{-1}\phi\neq \psi$ but say it equals $\psi\:'$?

Comment: Was that the direction you had trouble with? If you now see it, you are welcome to post the argument as an answer. That way you get feedback on the presentation, and any lingering unclear points come to surface.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you. I will post my answer after I finish studying for another class.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have proved containment in one direction, and these are finite sets, you can finish the proof by showing that the sets have the same cardinality.  Since the symbols are arbitrary, the number of mappings in $S_{26}$ taking any three distinct symbols to any three distinct symbols (in order) is always the same.  In fact, it's $23!$, since that's how many choices there are for the destinations of the other letters.  Thus, the number of $\phi$s on the left and the number of $\psi$s on the right are the same.  Since left-multiplication is 1-1, this is the same as the number of $\sigma\psi$s on the right, and you are done.